# How to get Data from database Based Id SpringBoot Java

Tags: java, postgresql, rest, spring-boot, web-services

I build simple REST service, I want to get data just data key from database based id but, when I running no result showing in postman, how can I fix it?
please help meee....

This is My Repository

```
public interface GenerateKeyRepository extends JpaRepository<KeyEntity, Integer>
{
Optional<KeyEntity> findById(Integer id);

}
```

This is My Controller

```
@GetMapping(path= "/getById/{company_id}")

String getById(@RequestBody KeyEntity keyEntity, @PathVariable int company_id){
String encKey= null;

    KeyEntity key = new KeyEntity();

    encKey= key.getKeyencrypted();

    gkrepo.findById(company_id);

    return encKey;

}
```

This is My Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "tb_key")
public class KeyEntity {

@Id
private Integer companyid;
private Date creationdate;
private String keyencrypted;

public Integer getCompanyid() {
    return companyid;
}
public void setCompanyid(Integer companyid) {
    this.companyid = companyid;
}
public Date getCreationdate() {
    return creationdate;
}
public void setCreationdate(Date creationdate) {
    this.creationdate = creationdate;
}
public String getKeyencrypted() {
    return keyencrypted;
}
public void setKeyencrypted(String keyencrypted) {
    this.keyencrypted = keyencrypted;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "KeyEntity [companyid=" + companyid + ", creationdate=" + creationdate + ", keyencrypted=" + keyencrypted
            + "]";
}



}
```

Comment: Could you please add your Entity code also.

Comment: Oke I have add my entity.., please give me answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code. It might help.

```
@GetMapping(path= "/getById/{company_id}")
String getById(@RequestBody KeyEntity keyEntity, @PathVariable int company_id){
String encKey= null;
KeyEntity key = gkrepo.findById(company_id).get();
encKey= key.getKeyencrypted();
return encKey;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Assign the return result of `gkrepo.findById(company_id);` to a variable and then get the encrypted key from that variable. Then return from your controller.
Currently, you are creating a new KeyEntity object yourself and not using the repository result.

Comment: how i do that? please give me example?

Comment: You could try like this -
`Optional<KeyEntity> key = gkrepo.findById(company_id);
   if (null != key && key.isPresent()) {
encKey = key.get().getKeyencrypted();
}
`

Comment: Also, your variables should use lowerCamelCase e.g. keyEncrypted instead of keyencrypted - as a better programming practice.